# Error while loading nodelet [/normal_estimation]

Tags: ros, ros-pcl, ros-fuerte, nodelets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm using ROS Fuerte Beta 1 on Ubuntu 11.10.
I tried to compile pcl_ros nodelets. There were some errors related to old PCL library API, I fixed them. When I try `roslaunch Package node.launch` I receive next error:

```
[ERROR] [1334687385.411350875]: Failed to load nodelet [/normal_estimation] of type [pcl/NormalEstimation]: Failed to load library /home/crady/ros/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_features.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /home/crady/ros/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_features.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl18BoundaryEstimationINS_8PointXYZENS_6NormalENS_8BoundaryEE14computeFeatureERNS_10PointCloudIS3_EE
[FATAL] [1334687385.412377822]: Service call failed!
```

So, seems that pcl::BoundryEstimation<PointXYZ, Normal, Boundry>::computeFeature(PointCloud) is missing. Where may be problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32039/error-while-loading-nodelet-%5B/normal_estimation%5D/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-17**:
It might help to know the exact roslaunch code you are using.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-17**:
http://pastebin.com/gAVqdVk7  here it is.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-18**:
Some additions: nodelet manager fails to load exactly this nodelet, other works fine. Error says that it missing library that contains this symbol (BoundryEstimation). I assume that somewhere in manifest.xml or plugin.xml for pcl_ros missed this link. But I can't find it for this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Aha! You are using Fuerte. It looks like that version of pcl_ros is missing the libpcl_ros_features.so.

Please file a bug report.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-18**:
Hm. But I have it in perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib. In CMakeLists.txt section for this nodelets was commented out, but I uncommented it. http://pastebin.com/cUDg83Kw this is my version of CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-18**:
I see. I noticed it was missing in the Ubuntu pcl_ros binary. That suggests that it was broken somehow and needs some repair for Fuerte. I don't see an open Trac ticket for it.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-18**:
I file the bug report - https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5426

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-11-07**:
Thank you @CaptainTrunky! This helped me find the issue with shared objects for features and segmentation. But I get errors when I rosmake pcl_ros after these changes. I have posted a new question - http://answers.ros.org/question/47814/ros-fuerte-pcl-features-surface-and-segmentation-libraries/

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-11-08**:
It would be great if you could share with us if you faced these issues and how you fixed them. Thank you.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-27**:
I am facing similar kind of problems. I have posted a new question http://answers.ros.org/question/157886/error-while-loading-nodelet-velocity_multiplexer/. Thanks in advance.